Plastic plugs used to fasten cover over radiator
2010 Silverado 1500
What are these plastic plugs/fasteners called?



I ask because most of those fasteners are broken or missing on my truck.
I'd like to research these things and replace them with something more robust. (But I'm not sure how yet, especially since some of the fasteners insert into steel bracing while others insert into plastic housing, so it's hard to find a solution that will work with both materials.)



"replace them with something more robust." Last time I needed to replace a few, I used bolts, nuts and washers.

These are useful because they work from the one accessible side.  If you did use nuts and bolts, you'd have to hold the nut or bolt on the other side.  So an alternative is a "threadded clip" or "clip-threadded fastener" that holds itself in place over a lip, and allows the use of a sheet metal screw.

There are tools which will remove them properly: google for "push pin removal tool". Otherwise, removing them is an exercise in frustration. You probably want the pliers type.

@Criggie Threaded inserts might be an option too. https://i.sstatic.net/FyXv9CzV.jpg https://www.princessauto.com/en/150-pc-metric-steel-threaded-inserts-kit/product/PA0008845190 But I wonder if they’d slip/spin in the hole due to not having enough grip. Maybe some sort of glue like construction adhesive would help.

@User1974 Rivnuts  yes I use them on bike frames to add water bottles etc.  They require an accurately-sized round hole but would be an excellent idea here too.   (comments because question was about name of plastic pin, not asked about replacements)

They're probably broken or missing because mechanics have had to remove them at some point in the past, and didn't replace the broken ones when they put the cover back on. If you replace them with something more robust, make sure it's still easy to get off when work needs to be done. I would replace like for like, and on a 14 year old vehicle I would ask myself if the cover needs to be there at all.

I'm sure they are called several different names, but a search for "push fasteners rivet clip" on Google will get you what you're looking for.

Aliexpress call them Push Clips, Bumper Clips, Auto Clips, Car Rivets and Plastic Rivets.

You can get them on Amazon e.g. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L6FJGR4?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1
